# Problem with function not finishing because of async?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, aws-lambda, async-await

The code inside the comment block does not work, if I put it inside an if statement.

I think the main issue is that it happens to be before a return statement, so how can I make sure it finishes running before return is initiated.

I've tried `let {cool} = await ....` with no luck

The intent is to copy and paste the code from above to inside the if statement.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.region = "us-east-1";
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  ////----------------------------THIS CODE HERE WORKS-------------------------------------------///////
  var PayloadObj = {
    amount: String(event["amount"]),
    email: String(event["email"]),
  };

  var Payload = JSON.stringify(PayloadObj);
  var params = {
    FunctionName: "lambda-2", // the lambda function we are going to invoke
    Payload: Payload,
  };
  let { cool } = lambda.invoke(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(data.Payload);
    }
  });

  //-------------------------------------END of this CODE --------------------------------------////

  // TODO implement

  const stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test");

  var amount = event["amount"];
  var token = event["token"];

  let { status } = await stripe.charges.create({
    amount: amount * 100,
    currency: "usd",
    description: amount,
    source: token,
  });

  if (status === "succeeded") {
    //--------------------------------Same code here!-------------------------------///
    // same code from above
    //---------------------------Does not work!!------------------------------------------//

    const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(status),
    };
    return response;
  } else {
    const response = {
      statusCode: 402,
      body: JSON.stringify("Payment Failed"),
    };
    return response;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using await, you don't need to use call back function to display data and error. You can just use try-catch block.

```js
var PayloadObj = {
  amount: String(event["amount"]),
  email: String(event["email"]),
};

var Payload = JSON.stringify(PayloadObj);
var params = {
  FunctionName: "lambda-2", // the lambda function we are going to invoke
  InvocationType: "RequestResponse", // InvocationType: "Event",
  Payload: Payload,
};

try{
  const data = await lambda.invoke(params).promise();
  console.log(data.payload);
}catch(err){
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: did not fix the main problem

Comment: do you need to add InvocationType: 'Event' in params?

Comment: does it work? I read AWS doc says "To invoke a function asynchronously, set InvocationType to Event". Default InvocationType is "RequestREsponse"

Comment: Forgot to mention, you need to add promise() after invoke function